# having a hard time with php redirect header, am i doint it right?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

i have this code in my index.php @line 3

```
    if(check_login()==true){
header('location: chat/chat.php');
```

and this one in my init.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require('const.php');
    require($db_file);
    function check_login($username,$enroll) {
        if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['enroll'])) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    function get_username() {
        return $_SESSION['username'];
    }
    function get_enroll() {
        return $_SESSION['enroll'];
    }
    ?>
```

it always says this line in my page and cant proceed to log in
Warning: Missing argument 1 for check_login(), called in /home/a2502890/public_html/index.php on line 3 and defined in /home/a2502890/public_html/includes/init.php on line 5

im trying to create a simple chat site for my school project

Comment: seems clear to me, `check_login()` takes two arguments `($username,$enroll)`, you give it ZERO

Comment: make sure you start your session. `session_start();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a function called check_login with two required parameters. $username and $enroll.

Yet on line 3, the code at the top, you're using `check_login()` without passing in those parameters hence the issue.

Based on what I can see here it looks like you need to remove $username and $enroll from check_login. E.g:

```
function check_login() {
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
function check_login($username,$enroll)
```

to

```
function check_login()
```

i dont know why you have those parameters when you are not using them.

Comment: I would suggest doing the opposite. Force the session variables to be passed as parameters so that function isn't coupled tightly into the system.

Comment: hahah that was simple, thank you for that!
but i still cant seem to get out of that log in page, its not redirecting

Comment: that would mean the session is not set.